# Changing Wordpress domain

Tags: migration

Since most previous questions deal only with the fundamentals of Wordpress migration, I haven't managed to find much information on this. Working in customer support for a webhosting company I've done this a million times but now that I've done a few of my own websites, I've finally come upon a problem I can't deal with myself:

Nothing would suggest that my case was any different from my past experience - I created a subpage with only very few plugins, only significant one would be Elementor (I also made a few changes to the Astra theme's CSS but mostly just changed colors around).

I changed my website's address from https://website.com/test to https://test.website.com using Wordpress Tools app (not sure if it's public but it works the same way as the Search&Replace script or any other plugin used for database migration). I didn't move the contents on FTP at all and the DNS and server settings are definitely okay. This time however, the entire theme and Elementor editor completely broke down. Wordpress admin works without any other issues though.

This is how the website should look: https://paste.pics/3d2092a237453903e9accbd3924c7416

And here's the result of migration: https://paste.pics/eabdd7cbf3508fe3657a61c89c3b2afb

Any ideas what I'm missing?

Comment: What do your console errors say

Comment: Only general 404 errors:

GET https://......./wp-content/uploads/elementor/css/post-146.css?ver=1627748878 net::ERR_ABORTED 404
...../:44 GET https://......./wp-content/uploads/elementor/css/post-109.css?ver=1627747634 net::ERR_ABORTED 404
...../:487 GET https://......./wp-includes/js/dist/vendor/regenerator-runtime.min.js?ver=0.13.7 net::ERR_ABORTED 404
...../:470 GET https://......./wp-content/uploads/2021/07/testikomat-gold-white-768x165.png 404
...../:470 GET https://......./wp-content/uploads/2021/07/logo-full-gold-768x131.png 404

Comment: I feel like I'm missing something small yet important. Everything works fine on my site as long as I keep the folder in the url (/test). I'm using the following htaccess rewrite to redirect the subdomain.  Shouldn't that, paired with renamed Wordpress, be enough for all requests to be directed to correct files?
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^test\.website\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !^/test/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /test/$1 [L,QSA]

Comment: Apparently Elementor has a feature somewhere in the settings for changing domains.  I don't use it myself but this discussion did come up the other day.

Beyond that, use Better Search and Replace to make sure serialized data gets updated properly.